# Unable to reach googlewebmasterstools.html file using DNS name, but able to access via IPADDRESS

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress

Note : Asked this question on wordpress.stackexchange.com, it was recommended to ask here.

I am trying to get webmastertools to verify my ownership on my domain. `www.swipetelecom.com`.

**Issue :**
When I try to reach the googlewebmastertools.html file, using http://www.swipetelecom.com/googlewebmasterstools.html. I get a 404

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /googlewebmasterstools.html was not found on this server.

**But :**
I am able to reach the googlewebmasterstools.html file using the `1.2.3.4/wordpress/googlemastertools.html`.

I am using a local domain manager (not godaddy). I have setup Frame Forwarding at the domain manager. Does it have something to do with this ?

This is my .htaccess (in my /var/www/html/wordpress folder), does it have anything to do with this ?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My wordpress folder and all their contents are owned by `www-data`.

What am I missing here ?

And yes, I have tried all other methods of verification, but none of them work too. This is the most logical question I could ask here.

Comment: I able to access site and home page running fine..inner pages are not working I think , right?

Comment: Yes, The website is working perfectly fine. But inner pages are not.

Comment: do you able to access wp-admin?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access admin pages, I am able to view the website. I am also able to see that googlewebmaster html file using the ipaddress. Just via the DNS the file is not visible.

Comment: So issue is you are not able to access googlewebmaster pages OR your site inner pages?

Comment: I have clarified the question further. If I use http://ipaddress/wordpress/googlewebmasterstools.html it works. But when I use http://www.swipetelecom.com/googlewebmasterstools.html, i get a 404.

Comment: Do not confuse, I am able to access ALL (completely) the pages and the entire website. I am just not able to verify my webmasterstools via the DNS name.

Comment: But I think you have move site from http://54.169.149.94/wordpress/ TO  swipetelecom.com , Right?

Comment: No, swipetelecom.com is "frame forwarded to" 54.169.149.94/wordpress.

Comment: I see.I think issue looks from server side. still you please wait if anyone expert here can you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frames will not do what you are trying to achieve. You are iframing content from another server/ip (server 2) which is completely separate from the server/ip (server 1) hosting your index page with the frame on it. So since you have your Google verification file on server 2 you will be unable to call that path from server 1 since nothing is actually located there.

I would recommend making /wordpress/ the web root for server 2 then just changing your A record for swipetelecom.com to 54.169.149.94 from 180.149.240.169.

Alternatively you could just upload your Google verification file to server 1 (180.149.240.169).

Comment: Can I just change the A record of swipetelecom.com to 54.169.149.94/wordpress ? Since if I do what you are saying I will also have to edit .htaccess ?

Comment: I have a option to use "Standard Forwarding". But the description of this type of forwarding is not clear. `Redirect website visitors to another site and show them the destination address. Use the 301 code if you moved the site permanently to this address - such redirection will keep the site's search engines rankings. The code 302 can be used to redirect visitors to a temporary site copy, when you do not want search engines to index this temporary site.`

Comment: DNS is oblivious to any paths or port numbers, it only turns names into ip addresses so you would be unable to set the A record to "54.169.149.94/wordpress". Though i still suggest charging the A record to "54.169.149.94" because i don't really see the point in the current setup and framing. After the domain is pointed to server 2 you could either just upload an index.php file to the web root and make it auto redirect to /wordpress but then you will constantly see www.swipetelecom.com/wordpress which isn't as pretty as just www.swipetelecom.com. 1/2

Comment: If you have full access to server 2 you can just edit the Apache webserver config to change the webroot to /wordpress. 2/2

Comment: Ok, I'll make the change on the A record also change the webroot to /wordpress. Should I also change my DNS forwarding to `Standard Forwarding` from the current `Frame Forwarding` ?

Comment: Once you change the A record and the webroot you will no longer need to forward anything or use a frame at all.